make an image take up maximum space of viewport
Creating an application that can draw html element on an image.
The editor has a floating toolbar, it has an image and on the top of the image it has a div, that contains all the html elements like textbox, checkbox, labels etc.
The basic structure for now is the following I have a container div inside the container I have an img tag for the image and a div.
I want to make sure that, the image takes up the maximum amount of space in the viewport. For example if I have a really wide image (w:1000, h:300) then I should have black bars on the top and the bottom, if I have a really narrow image (w:300: h:1000) it should have black bars on the right and the left sides.
The way it works is that the image should always keep the aspect ratio and should always take up the maximum space. The content div should be the exact size as the img element so in every screen the elements inside it appears in the same position.
I already tried object-fit which does what I want it looks perfect but in the background it makes the size of the image match the size of the viewport which includes the black bars so the content div cant be the same size as the image what appears on the screen.
I managed to find a solution that works for narrow images, but when using a wide image the image just sits in the middle of the screen with black bars on the top and bottom and the sides as well.


body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/300">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>



I found similar problems online, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I also considering using JavaScript to solve the problem.
I tried object-fit, and native CSS but I couldn't make it work. I expect the image to be in the middle, take up the maximum space in the viewport and keep aspect-ratio even if I resize it really small, should work like the Netflix player but not for video and also for really narrow and really wide images.

Could you make the snippet a bit more realistic - e.g. with some actual typical content that is to go on top of the image.

Does this answer your question? Make Image Fill Entire Screen Without Bounding Box?

@AHaworth the content on top of the images not in any way change the desired behaviour nor helps to solve it better, what im looking for is just an image, that takes up the maximum amount of space in a browser window, i just provided more information to help understand better what im trying to use this for, sorry if it mislead  you in any way

@HeikoTheißen the question is similar, but the provided asnwers seems to work exactly the same as the snippet i provided, it works fine with portrait oriented narrow images, but there are a lot of space on the sides with landscape oriented wide images

I thought the point was that you needed the text on top to be on top of the image and not stray into the sides, so object-fit contain was t enough as it doesn’t alter the width for example of the container.
